# Have voronoi diagram and need it placed in a state map

Tags: r, ggplot2, voronoi

I have code below given to me by someone on this site, and thank you all for that!
I need to incorporate this diagram into the great state of Texas!  I have my code posted so far, is it a stretch to put it in a state?

```
n <- c(30.60688, 30.28370, 31.08425, 29.29955, 32.71078)
k <- c(-96.35286, -97.73405, -97.34860, -94.79447, -97.36118)
mat <- cbind(n, k)
df <- as.data.frame(mat)
names(df) <- c('x','y')

# triangulate
xrng <- expand_range(range(df$x), .05)
yrng <- expand_range(range(df$y), .05)
deldir <- deldir(df, rw = c(xrng, yrng))

# voronoi
map('state', 'texas')
qplot(x, y, data = df)  +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2), size = .25,
    data = deldir$dirsgs, linetype = 2
  ) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some research...

```
library(ggplot2)
allStates <- map_data('state')
texas <- subset(allStates, region == 'texas')
head(texas)

# triangulate
n <- c(30.60688, 30.28370, 31.08425, 29.29955, 32.71078)
k <- c(-96.35286, -97.73405, -97.34860, -94.79447, -97.36118)
mat <- cbind(n, k)
df <- as.data.frame(mat)
names(df) <- c('x','y')

xrng <- expand_range(range(df$x), .05)
yrng <- expand_range(range(df$y), .05)
deldir_ds <- deldir(df, rw = c(xrng, yrng))$dirsgs

# voronoi
ggplot(texas, aes(x = long, y = lat))  + 
  geom_polygon(fill = 'grey25') +
  geom_segment(data = deldir_ds,
           aes(x = y1, y = x1, xend = y2, yend = x2), 
           size = .25, linetype = 2, color = rgb(229/255, 229/255, 229/255)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, if it's what you need.  Feel free to accept my answer... :)

Comment: What do you use for your research on this stuff?  I can never seem to find what I need.  Also, do you know which part of the code controls how long the lines are?  I am trying to play around with it and can't make them any longer.

Comment: I've been working with `ggplot2` for a few years, so it's just getting used to that library.  Check out Hadley's site for loads of answers - docs.ggplot2.org/current.  If you want to extend the lines, change the `.05` parameters in the expand_range function.  If you increase that to `0.15`, it'll be noticeably longer...  Stoked to hear that you're interested in becoming a useR!

Comment: Yeah, you would need to add `geom_point(other_data_set, aes(x = lat, y = long)) + ` to the ggplot